# How to convert dictionary to a string angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am currently working on my project using angularjs. I got everything already it is just that, i need to convert the dictionary list to a string separated by comma. I can only do this using python.

```
[{"name":"john"},{"name":"mark"},{"name":"peter"}]
```

I want to convert them to string

```
"john,mark,peter"
```

I would really appreciate your help. :)

Comment: it would be simply something like `var names = array.map(function(val){ return val.name; }).join(',')` inside controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.map` and then `.join` will do

```
var array = [{"name":"john"},{"name":"mark"},{"name":"peter"}];
var names = array.map(function(item) {
   return item.name;
}).join(',');
```

Answer (score 1):

The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a function for every array element. Use this to loop and then add that value to a  variable.

```
var dict=[{"name":"john"},{"name":"mark"},{"name":"peter"}];
var string;
dict.map(function(value){
   //do any stuff here
  string+=value["name"]+",";
});
console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `map` function to concatenate the values:

```js
var dict=[{"name":"john"},{"name":"mark"},{"name":"peter"}];

var str="";
dict.map(function(a){
  str+=a["name"]+",";
});

//feels ironical as question has AngularJS tag
document.getElementById("log").innerText=str;
```

```html
<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: this will add unnecessary `,` at the end.

Comment: Yes, @PankajParkar don't know what is worse, calling `join` after `map` or using `substring` to remove trailing comma :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate over each key-value pair and concat the extracted value with comma.

```
var obj =  [{"name":"john"},{"name":"mark"},{"name":"peter"}]
var result = '';
for (var p in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            result += obj[p].name + ",";
        }
 }

result = result.replace(/,$/g,''); // to trim trailing comma
```